# Issue inside for..in loop

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a function that checks whether two arrays are identical or not and I'm currently stuck at checking whether two objects *(that could be inside an array)* are identical.

To explain my code a little bit, I have a variable named **`eq`** that's returned when the function is over and it should contain either **`true`** for each element of the first array that exists in the second array or **`undefined`** if an element doesn't.

Also, I use a recursive IIFE to check if the object has sub-objects and the sub-objects are also identical. To check whether an array element is an object literal I use **`el.constructor === Object`**.

Without being 100% certain, I believe that I've done something wrong inside the **`for..in`** loops.

**Code:**

```js
function equals(a, b) {
  return (a === b && a !== null) || (a.length === b.length && (function(a, b) {
    var eq = [];

    a.forEach(function(el1, index) {
      b.forEach(function(el2) {
        if (el1 === el2) eq[index] = true;
        else if (el1.constructor === el2.constructor && el1.constructor === Object) {
          /* a -> the object of the first array
           * b -> the object of the second array
           * c -> eq[index] then eq[index][i] provided how deep it goes */
          (function rec(a, b, c) {
            c = [];
            var i = 0;
            for (var prop in a) {
              for (var attr in b) {
                if (prop === attr && a[prop] === b[attr]) c[i] = true;
                else if (prop === attr && a[prop].constructor === b[attr].constructor
                  && a[prop].constructor === Object) {
                    rec(a[prop], b[attr], eq[index][i]);
                  }
              }
              i++;
            }
          })(el1, el2, eq[index]);
        }
      });
    });
    return /*!~eq.indexOf(undefined);*/ eq;
  })(a, b));
}

/* Use */
var a = [1, {a: "a", b: "b" }, 4, 6],
    b = [{a: "a", b: "b"}, 1, 7, 6];

equals(a, b);
```

---

**Example 1:** *(works fine for simple arrays)*

```
var
   a = [1, 3, 4, 6],
   b = [3, 1, 7, 6];

equals(a, b); // returns: [true, true, undefined, true]
```

**Example 2:** *(doesn't work for objects)*

```
var
   a = [1, {a: "a", b: "b"}, 4, 6],
   b = [{a: "a", b: "b"}, 1, 7, 6];

equals(a, b); /* returns: [true, undefined, undefined, true]
                 SHOULD return: [true, [true, true], undefined, true] */
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a function that compares two arrays already exists in one of the numerous libraries and frameworks. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: It's an exercise for my college @HubertGrzeskowiak :)

Comment: Ah okay. And are you sure you want to compare the arrays ignoring the elements' order?

Comment: Yep, that's what the exercise says, but still if we exclude objects the function works without sorting the arrays. There's going to be a problem with duplicate values, but I have a solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hubert Grzeskowiak mentions [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39639315/6313073) the problem lies in **`c`** not having any connection whatsoever with **`eq[index]`**.

A quick solution I came up with that solves the issue is deleting **`c = []`** and declaring **`eq[index][i]`** as an array at the time it's passed to **`rec`** as shown in the code below:

**Code:** *(Just the IIFE)*

```
(function rec(a, b, c) {
   var i = 0;
   for (var prop in a) {
      for (var attr in b) {
         console.log(i)
         if (prop === attr && a[prop] === b[attr]) c[i] = true;
         else if (prop === attr && a[prop].constructor === b[attr].constructor &&
            a[prop].constructor === Object) {
               rec(a[prop], b[attr], (eq[index][i] = [])); // ← instead of eq[index][i]
         }
      }
      i++;
   }
})(eachA, eachB, eq[index]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem lies in your `eq[index]` being passed to the comparator function. This doesn't pass a reference, but simply an undefined value. By setting `c = []` inside the function you are overriding that undefined by a new array. There is no connection to `eq` whatsoever. Restructure your code so that you either create the array in `eq[index]` outside `rec` and pass it in (`c`). Or make the function `rec` return a value.

Comment: Thanks @Hubert, your answer gave me some good food for thought. I found a way around by declaring **`eq[index][i]`** as an array at the time it's passed to **`rec`**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a take on it. The code could use some shortening and I didn't test it excessively but the recursion seems to work for nestled content of any depth.

```js
var
    a = [1, {a: "a", b: "b"}, 4, [1,{c:5,d:[1,2]}], 6],
    b = [{a: "a", b: "b"}, [1,{c:5,d:[1,2]}], 1, 4, 6];

/*
 * returns 'true' if arrays are the same
 *
 * depends on 'checkObjects'
 */
function checkArrays(arrayA, arrayB) {
    if (arrayA === arrayB) return true;
    if (arrayA === null || arrayB === null) return false;
    if (arrayA.length !== arrayB.length) return false;

    // since the order doesn't matter we sort the arrays
    arrayA.sort();
    arrayB.sort();

    var arrayLength = arrayA.length; // stored for performance
    for (var i = 0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
        // if same value we continue through the array
        // else they are not the same and we can stop
        if (typeof arrayA[i] === 'object' && typeof arrayB[i] === 'object') {
            if (!checkObjects(arrayA[i], arrayB[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (typeof arrayA[i] === 'array' && typeof arrayB[i] === 'array') {
            if (!checkArrays(arrayA[i], arrayB[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (arrayA[i] !== arrayB[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // if we get here the values are equal
    return true;
}

/*
 * returns 'true' if objects are the same
 *
 * depends on 'checkArrays'
 */
function checkObjects(objectA, objectB) {
    if (objectA === objectB) return true;
    if (Object.keys(objectA).length !== Object.keys(objectB).length) return false;

    var keys = Object.keys(objectA),
        numberOfKeys = keys.length; // stored for performance
    for (var i=0; i<numberOfKeys; i++) {
        if (!(keys[i] in objectB)) {
            return false; // objects don't have the same keys
        } else {
            if (!(objectA[keys[i]] === objectB[keys[i]])) {
                // if same key-value-pairs exist we continue through the array
                // else they are not the same and we can stop
                if (typeof objectA[keys[i]] === 'array' && typeof objectB[keys[i]] === 'array') {
                    if (!checkArrays(objectA[keys[i]], objectB[keys[i]])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else if (typeof objectA[keys[i]] === 'object' && typeof objectB[keys[i]] === 'object') {
                    if (!checkObjects(objectA[keys[i]], objectB[keys[i]])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // if we get here the key-value-pairs are equal
    return true;
}

console.log(checkArrays(a, b));
```